# given an input array and sum, return the minimum elements need to get sum

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue, binary-heap

The problem is a variation of `selection algorithm` in selecting the fewest number of items whose sum is at least some value, N. For example you might want to have a list of items whose sum is 5,000 or more, but you don’t want more items than you have to take from an input list. So if one number is 5,001, then your output list will contain a single number.

another example: `Input list {3,4,5,1,2} target = {8}.`
`output list will be : {5,3}`.

This problem has been shown to solve using `binaryHeap` in this [excellent series of posts](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/10/03/uses-for-heaps/);
but when I implemented in `Java`, I do not get the desired the output. I get the entire `input list`.
I am not able to find out the exact cause of the problem. Here is my code;

```
public class SelectTopSum {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {5,2,10,1,33};
        int target=33;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selectTop(arr, target)));
    }

    private static int[] selectTop(int[] arr, int sum) {
        //get max heap
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
        });
        int runningTot=0;

        for (int i : arr) {
            if (runningTot<sum) {
                runningTot+=i;
                pq.add(i);
            }
            else if (i > pq.peek()) {
                runningTot-=pq.remove();
                runningTot+=i;
                pq.add(i);
            }
            while (runningTot-pq.peek()>=sum) {
                runningTot-=pq.remove();
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("priority queue is "+ pq);

        int[] result=new int[pq.size()];
        int i=0;
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            result[i]=pq.remove();
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison is the wrong way around.

[`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) puts the *smallest* item (based on your comparison) *first*, and, by saying `return o2.compareTo(o1);`, you'll treat the largest integer as the smallest, but you need the smallest element needs to be first, not the largest.

You need to change that to:

```
return o1.compareTo(o2);
```

(note that I swapped the `o1` and `o2`)

Or, for what it's worth, you can remove the second argument completely from the constructor, as it will then use `Integer.compareTo`, which will do what you want.

Comment: but I don't want the smallest item to be on top of heap, I want the largest on top, so I can remove it..?

Comment: and still it works for some but not for all inputs. `eg :int[] arr = {5,1,10,32}; int target=33; gives [10, 32]`, while it should give [32,1]

Comment: You repeatedly remove the *smallest* if doing so would result in still being over the sum. What would then remain on the heap is the largest elements that sum up to at least the sum (which would also be the smallest number of elements). Then you return these. Consider your example in your code - first you add all the elements to the heap, then you remove 1, 2, 5 and 10, so we're left with 33, which you then return.

Comment: It's working as intended - both `[10, 32]` and `[1, 32]` are only 2 elements, so they are considered equally good. If you want to return the smallest possible sum as well, that problem's a lot more difficult and can't be solved with this approach.